# Smallest permutation of given number

Tags: python, string, algorithm, permutation

I've got a number as a string and I want to find the smallest number composed of original number digits, i.e.

```
56340902138765401345 -> 10001233344455566789
```

I'm converting the string to list and sorting it.

```
num = '56340902138765401345'
a = list(num)
a.sort()
```

As a number can't start with a zero (but I need to use zeros from the original number) I'm looking for the first nonzero element and put it in front:

```
inext = next(i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x != '0')
a.insert(0, a.pop(inext))
```

Then I'm converting list back to string and displaying it.

```
num2 = ''.join(map(str, a))
print(num2)
```

It works but it doesn't seem very pythonic or elegant to me. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why isn't `00011233344455566789` the smallest permutation of your number? You can't have leading zeroes?

Comment: Yes, I can't have leading zeros.

Comment: It's seems like a pretty reasonable way to me. It will also work with numbers in other bases and non-numeric digits, eg. hexadecimal strings.

Comment: You could use `a = sorted(num)` to save a line. And you don't have to `map` to `str` since your elements are already strings, so `num2 = ''.join(a)` is enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can count the zeroes. Then we remove the zeroes from the number, we sort it and reassemble it. To reassemble we use the first digit, then we add back our zeroes and then the rest of our sorted number.

```
num = '56340902138765401345'

nzeros = num.count('0')
num = ''.join(sorted(num.replace('0', '')))
print num[0] + ('0' * nzeros) + num[1:]
```

Result:

```
 10001233344455566789
```

Comment: I did exactly the same XD

Comment: I vote downvoted but in the previous answer from you, now let me put upvote not until you edit

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of minor things that could be improved.

```
a = list(num)
a.sort()
```

can be replaced with

```
a = sorted(num)
```

The string can be reconstituted from the list with `''.join(sorted(num)`.

Putting that together you could use a regular expression to move the leading zeroes behind the first non-zero digit:

```
import re
a = re.sub(r'^(0+)(.)', r'\2\1', ''.join(sorted(num)))
```

I wouldn't argue that this is more Pythonic, but it is pretty succinct, and possibly more elegant (depending on the beholder, that is).

Comment: I like your answer, but I think using a regex is far less pythonic than OP's original approach

Comment: @MarcusMüller:  Oh, yes, I agree that it's not particularly Pythonic.

Comment: It's very elegant but I'd prefer not to use re when not necessary (as Zawinski's quote comes to mind...)

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
num = "".join(sorted(num))
nonzero = num.rfind("0") + 1
if nonzero:
    num[0] = num[nonzero]
    num[nonzero] = "0"
```

If there's no `"0"` in num, then `rfind` return `-1`, so `nonzero` evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def Function():
    num=int(input("Enter your number: "))
    num1=str(num)
    list1=[]
    count1=0
    for i in num1:
        if i == "0":
            count1 += 1
        else:
            list1.append(int(i))

    list1.sort()
    s = ""
    if count1 > 0:
        for i in range(len(list1)):
            if i == 0:
                s += str(list1[i])
                for j in range(count1):
                    s += "0"
            else:
                s += str(list1[i])
    else:
        for i in list1:
            s += str(i)
        print(int(s))


if __name__=="__main__":
    Function()
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].